How can flexbox be used to re-arrange elements when responsively switching between single line and multi-line format?
I have a group of form inputs that are displayed on a single line on larger viewports and collapses to a multi-line display on smaller viewports. On the single line display I want a cancel button at the end of the line, but on the multi-line display I want it at the end of the first line, and I want the ends of both lines to be flush with each other.
I can do this by having two cancel buttons and conditionally displaying each based on a media query, as my snippet below shows, but it would be better to only have one button and shift its position based on the media query. Is there a way to do that in an example like mine by leveraging flexbox instead of using multiple cancel buttons? It seems like something that should be possible, but I can't imagine exactly how to do it.


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  input[name="qty"] {
    width: 36px;
  }
  input[name="unit"] {
    width: 192px;
  }
  button {
    width: 72px;
  }
  input[name="item"] {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .group-2 button {
    display: none;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    fieldset {
      display: flex;
    }
    .group-1 button {
      display: none;
    }
    .group-2 button {
      display: inline;
    }
  }
<fieldset>
  <div class="group-1">
    <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="qty" /><input
      type="text"
      name="unit"
      placeholder="unit"
    /><button type="button">CANCEL</button>
  </div>
  <div class="group-2">
    <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="item" /><button
      type="button"
    >
      CANCEL
    </button>
  </div>
</fieldset>




Why do you want the Cancel button at the end of the first line? Action buttons (like submit and cancel) should appear after inputs, at the end of the form, not in the “middle” of a group of form controls.

@MartinBean I see quite a few forms that have the submit button in the top right corner, then why not this variant?

@KIKOSoftware Because it just goes against the convention of left-to-right, top-to-bottom in an LTR language such as English. I guarantee it’ll also be harder to use for people with cognitive disabilities. It also just makes sense to go fields-actions, rather than fields-actions-more fields.

@MartinBean I fully agree, but the question is a good and interesting question without it telling us exactly why this is needed. The word "should", in your first comment, implies there's something actually wrong with the placement. I don't think there is. It is a deviation from the convention, or what you perceive as such, no more.

@MartinBean It's a rare case for me. I'm building a somewhat complicated form, with "mobile-first" in mind. My example represents one line item in a recipe, and I want maximum space to type in the "item" input, so that it is as visually readable as possible when being modified. The cancel button removes the entire line item, so it won't often be used while typing in the form, but maybe later when editing or re-ordering the list, so I gave it tabindex of -1, but I know I'll eventually have to consider how to make it obviously keyboard-actionable for best accessibility. https://ibb.co/6RKVZNt

(Note that in my demo image the up/down arrows are not a value spinner; qty is a text input. Those are handlebars for drag and drop.)

My attempt using container queries and grid display. Feel free to change gap and flex properties to match your design.


* { box-sizing: border-box; }

form {
  margin-block-start: 4rem;
  container: group / inline-size;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    
    input { 
      padding: .25rem;
      min-inline-size: 0; 
    }

    [name="qty"]  { flex: 1 }
    [name="unit"] { flex: 2 }
    [name="item"] { flex: 2 }

    

    @container group (width >= 700px) {
        display: flex;
        gap: .5rem;
        
        [class^="group"] {
          display: contents;
          flex: 1;
        }
    }
    
   
    @container group (width < 700px) {
      display: grid;
      gap: .5rem;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr fit-content(15rem);
      grid-template-areas: 
         "group1 button"
         "group2 group2"; 
     
      }
      
      [class^="group"] {
        display: flex;
        gap: .5rem;
        min-inline-size: 0
      }
      
      [name="unit"] { flex: 5 }
      .group-1 { grid-area: group1; }
      .group-2 { grid-area: group2; }
      button   { grid-area: button;  }
    }
  
}
<form >
  <fieldset>
    <div class="group-1">
      <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="qty" />
      <input type="text" name="unit" placeholder="unit" />
    </div>

    <div class="group-2">
      <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="item" />
    </div>
    
    <button type="button">CANCEL</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>




This is not as simple as I was expecting, but it works perfectly and includes relative responsive sizing of the inputs, so the entire fieldset can easily expand and contract with the viewport, without the need to respect hard-coded px sizes. It also puts the control button after the inputs in the document flow, a plus for accessibility and tabstop ordering.

You do not need the second div.
A single div with flexbox and flex-wrap:wrap will orient the elements as desired but it would be necessary to use order on the button at wider sizes to move it to the end.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[name="qty"] {
  width: 36px;
}

input[name="unit"] {
  width: 192px;
}

button {
  width: 72px;
}

input[name="item"] {
  width: 300px;
}

.group-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  button {
    order: 1;
  }
}
<fieldset>
  <div class="group-1">
    <input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="qty" />
    <input type="text" name="unit" placeholder="unit" />
    <button type="button">CANCEL</button>
    <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="item" />
  </div>
</fieldset>




This is a good answer because it shows how to solve this kind of problem with minimal code, and it can also be changed so that the button is the last element in the HTML document flow for better accessibility. The one problem I had is it did not work as expected at viewport width ~650-699. The button doesn't change position exactly when the fieldset collapses.
